# WiX ICE validation errors

Tags: wix, ice-validation

I'm having some strange issues with WiX on my local machine. The problem is intermittent, but after a few rebuilds of the solution, the WiX project starts throwing ICE validation errors.

If I go into my `AppData\Local\Temp` folder and delete all the temporary folders that contain the MSI, the solution compiles again. A short while later, the problem starts happening again. Having to keep clearing down the temp folders isn't a sustainable or satisfactory solution.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? The validation error codes seem to always be a combination of ICE30, ICE38, ICE64 and ICE91

Update:

As requested, here are the entries from the most recent failure:

> error LGHT0204: ICE38: ICE Internal Error 1002. API Returned:
>   1615.
>  error LGHT0204: ICE38: Error 2235: /OU.AppFramework.Includes.msi, _Profile, UPDATE `Directory` SET
>   `_Profile`=0
>  error LGHT0204: ICE64: ICE Internal Error 1001. API
>   Returned: 1615.
>  error LGHT0204: ICE64: Error 2242:
>   OU.AppFramework.Includes.msi, _Profile, ALTER TABLE `Directory` ADD
>   `_Profile` SHORT TEMPORARY HOLD
>  error LGHT0204: ICE91: ICE
>   Internal Error 1001. API Returned: 1615.
>  error LGHT0204: ICE91:
>   Error 2242: OU.AppFramework.Includes.msi, _Profile, ALTER TABLE
>   `Directory` ADD `_Profile` SHORT TEMPORARY HOLD

Interestingly, this failure occurred before I left the office last night, and the solution compiled OK when I came in this morning. As it seems to centre on the temp directory where the MSI is build by WiX, could it be the build process locking the file?

Update 2:

And now we're back to over 600 errors, mostly repetition of this error:

> error LGHT0204: ICE30: ICE Internal Error 100. API Returned: 1615.
>   error LGHT0204: ICE30: Error 2235: AppFramework.Includes.msi,
>   _ICE30SFN, SELECT `Directory_Parent`, `Directory`, `DefaultDir`, `_ICE30SFN`, `_ICE30LFN` FROM `Directory` WHERE
>   `Directory`.`Directory`=? AND `Directory_Parent`<>?

Update 3:

The problem still exists even after trying the suggestion by @limpan. There are a couple of warning given by light that are caused by the MSI output folder being locked when light tries to access the MSI:

> Warning 549 The directory '\AppData\Local\Temp\2opu3hxf' is in use and cannot be deleted. light.exe

Comment: can you please show us the log file. ICE30 can be caused by duplicate files in the installation.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I have similar issues

Comment: Not really. I've removed building of the WiX project from my Debug configuration and not seen the errors yet if I compile in Release but that hasn't actually fixed the issue

Answer (score 63):

Try adding `<RunWixToolsOutOfProc>true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc>` to your WiX project file.

We've had the same issue for a while, and tried various workarounds including deleting the temporary files and setting the msbuild environment variable.  These all appeared to work for a while, but eventually (sometimes after a few days) the problem would come back again.

I noticed that on my machine devenv.exe was the process that was locking the files that light.exe was trying to delete.  I also stumbled across an unrelated [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212773/uunable-to-see-wix-project-type-in-visual-studio-2008-2010) which mentioned this project setting to make the WiX tools run out of process.  I thought it could be worth a try and it appears to have cured the problem for us (so far...)

Comment: Wow added it to my Setup.proj file and never had this problem again. Thank you so much was so annoying having to close visual studio, delete the temporary .msi file and reload visual studio.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks a ton!

Comment: For those not sure the tag goes within the `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>` tags at the top of the file

Comment: Further clarification: add <RunWixToolsOutOfProc>true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc> to the first PropertyGroup in your .wixproj file.

Comment: This works! Thank-you! To further clarify how to add - first unload the wix project, then right click on the unloaded project and select 'edit blah.wixproj', add the mentioned node to the first property node in .wixproj. Can anyone explain what this actually does or where one could find details about this? I can't even find this in wix documentation.

Answer (score 48):

I had this issue as well and solved it in my environment.

**Short answer:**

Add the environment variable `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1` and restart Visual Studio

**Long answer:**

There was a warning during build that I first didn't see since I was too focused on the error:

> Failed to delete temporary directory: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\5[uniqueFolderName]         light.exe

I tried to remove the folder manually, but it was in use by another process.

It turns out that a lot of MSBuild.exe processes are started during build and then not closed again.
You can read more about the reason for that and what you can do to change that behavior in Stack Overflow question *[msbuild.exe staying open, locking files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919892)*.

This thread:  it and the solution in this thread:

I hope this answer can help someone else.

Comment: Finally managed to get back to looking at this issue. Looks like your suggestion might have fixed the problem @limpan. I've asked the team to add the environment variable and keep an eye on things for a day or 2. If nobody has any issues then that'll do for me!

Comment: After further investigation it doesn't look like to have the issue for us. Other devs on the team are still reporting WiX errors after adding the environment variable so it's not completely addressed the issue

Answer (score 19):

For *ICE30: ICE Internal Error 100. API Returned: 1615*, please try this and see if it works:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio (may be just the one that matters but just in case)
2. Go to `C:\Documents and Settings\\****user id****\\Local Settings\Temp\`.
3. Clear all the folders that look like this .. 's12qgaks'. Basically it contains the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) files
4. Open the solution and recompile.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Manu. Unfortunately I am already going through this each time, as indicated in my question.

Comment: For me it was just I didn't have rights to the directory even though I was administrator. I had to take ownership.

Answer (score 11):

I too had faced same the issue. In project properties, go to *Tool Settings* and click *Suppress ICE validation*.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks Sunil - I had spotted that but I'd rather try and get to the root cause of the problem and not just suppress it. It isn't happening on any of the other devs' machines so it's probably something about my set up. If I can't get any concrete answers here I could suppress the validation but that's going to affect everyone when I check the project file in

Answer (score 3):

For me MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1 (or /nr:false on command line) did not solve the problem.
But <RunWixToolsOutOfProc>true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc> did its job done.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  It turned out to be my Anti Virus software (OfficeScan)  It had the intermediate files created by Light.exe locked and the validation process failed. Excluding the temp folder from virus scan or turning off ICE validation is not an acceptable solution.

If anyone has a better solution. I would like to know.

Comment: Interesting - thanks @Mathew. Unfortunately I've now left that contract so may never get to the bottom of this one...