# Uunable to see WIX project type in Visual studio 2008/2010

Tags: wix, wix3.7, votive

I have Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and WIX37.msi (WIX 3.7) installed on my machine.

However, I am unable to see WIX project type in Visual studio 2008/2010.

Do I need to install additional tool/plugin?

Comment: Did you install WiX after VS 2008 / 2010? have you tried to re-install WiX?

Comment: Yes I installed WiX after 2008/2010.

Answer (score 2):

I have Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 installed on my machine and I installed WiX v3.7 RTM from [Codeplex](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514). Things work okay for me. There is a known issue in VS2008 that requires you to set an MSBuild property called `RunWixToolsOutOfProc` to `true`. This occurred because parts of WiX v3.7 were incorrectly built against the NETFX4.0 and VS2008 runs on NETFX2.0.

Comment: I also installed Wix from Codeplex only. Please help

Comment: At this point, it sounds like you need support. For that, I recommend contacting wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net and sending along the install logs and the Visual Studio log. Something is peculiar about your machine. :)

Comment: Thanks Rob!Do I need to install Votive (WIX plugin for visual studio)?

Comment: Also, one more query, I read somewhere that we can create xml using command line and create setup using Wix. Please provide me link for tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: You don't *need* Votive and the tutorial you're looking for can be found here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/tutorial. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Install v3.0 of WiX Toolset, to make it work with Visual Studio 2008. You can get it here: http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/44406

I don't know why it's not documented on their site but apparently you can't install the latest version (3.10 at the moment) and make it work with VS2008.

Comment: It would appear that v3.8 was the last version that will install on VS2008.