# Team Services can not build wix installer

Tags: msbuild, wix, azure-devops, wix3

I've chosen teams services (Visual studio online) as a new repository for my team, we working on the c# project. We're using WiX installer,

Team services msbuild can build our solution projects except for wix,

I have followed wix instruction for daily build instruction mentioned here http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html

I've added all required files in a folder, pushed into repository
the context of .wixproj is as following

```
<Project>
...

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixToolPath>$(SolutionDir)Tools\wix\3\bin\</WixToolPath>
    <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' != '' " />
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />-->
  <Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition="$(WixTargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
    <Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3 build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

but Teams services still complains as following

> light.exe(0,0): Error LGHT0217: Error executing ICE action 'ICE01'. The most common cause of this kind of ICE failure is an incorrectly
>   registered scripting engine. See
>   http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/error217/ for details and how to
>   solve this problem. The following string format was not expected by
>   the external UI message logger: "The Windows Installer Service could
>   not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not
>   correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for
>   assistance.".

how can I conquer over this issue?

Comment: Are you using the hosted build agent?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could resolve it by disabling validation via properties of wix installer,

more can be found here
[WiX ICE validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879411/wix-ice-validation-errors)